# Android Custom Loader, LoaderManagerImpl.LoaderInfo.callOnLoadFinished only called once

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I am trying to implement my own custom Android **Loader** to be able to use the **LoaderManager** benefits in my application (decoupling of loading data with lifecycle of my **Activities** and **Fragments**).

I have first considered subclassing from **AsyncLoader**, but I do not really need the loading of data to be put on an **AsyncTask** (that is what AsyncLoader does under the hood). The underlying data in my case is/are data/samples coming in from a native library. These samples are cashed in the library, which is completely asynchronous towards my applications, hence no need to iterate over this native cache within a separate thread.

Here is more or less how my Custom **Loader** looks like this:

```
public class TestSampleListLoader extends Loader<List<TestSample>> {
    private static final String TAG = "TestSampleListLoader";

    private NativeLibFactory mNativeLib = null;
    private SampleReader<TestSample> mTestSampleReader;
    private TestSampleListener mTestSampleSampleListener;
    private List<TestSample> mTestSampleList;

    public TestSampleListLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "TestSampleListLoader constructor!!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(List<TestSample> testSamples) {
        Log.i(TAG, "deliverResult(data) " + testSamples.size());
        super.deliverResult(testSamples);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStarted() {
        Log.i(TAG, "isStarted()");
        return super.isStarted();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartLoading()");
        super.onStartLoading();

        mTestSampleList = new ArrayList<TestSample>();

        if (null == mNativeLib) {
            initNativeLib();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void forceLoad() {
        Log.i(TAG, "forceLoad()");
        super.forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onForceLoad() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onForceLoad()");
        super.onForceLoad();

        mTestSampleList.clear();

        for (TestSample testSample : mTestSampleReader) {
            mTestSampleList.add(testSample);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "forceLoad(deliverResult) " + mTestSampleList.size());
        deliverResult(mTestSampleList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onReset()");

        mTestSampleList.clear();

        if (null != mTestSampleReader) {
            mTestSampleReader.close();
            mTestSampleReader = null;
        }
        if (null != mNativeLib) {
            mNativeLib.close();
            mNativeLib = null;
        }

        super.onReset();
    }

    @Override
    public void onContentChanged() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onContentChanged()");
        super.onContentChanged();
    }

    private void initNativeLib() {
        Log.i(TAG, "initNativeLib()");
        NativeLibAndroid.initNativeLib(getContext().getApplicationContext(), new NativeLibConnectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNativeLibReady(NativeLibFactory NativeLib) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onNativeLibReady!!!");
                mNativeLib = NativeLib;

                mTestSampleSampleListener = new TestSampleListener();
                mTestSampleReader = mNativeLib.createSampleReader(TestSample.class, mTestSampleSampleListener);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestSampleListener implements SampleReaderListener {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate() {
            Log.i(TAG, "TestSampleListener.onUpdate() => onContentChanged");
            TestSampleListLoader.this.onContentChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using a **Fragment** to display my native date samples by means of an **ArrayAdapter**:

```
public class TestSampleListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<TestSample>> {
    private static final String TAG = "TestSampleListFragment";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    // The Loader's id (this id is specific to the ListFragment's LoaderManager)
    private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

    // We use a custom ArrayAdapter to bind application info to the ListView.
    private TestSampleListAdapter mTestReaderAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceSample) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceSample);
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityCreated()");

        mTestReaderAdapter = new TestSampleListAdapter(getActivity());
        setEmptyText("No testSamples");
        setListAdapter(mTestReaderAdapter);
        setListShown(false);

        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Calling initLoader()!");
            if (getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID) == null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Initializing the new Loader...");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Reconnecting with existing Loader (id '1')...");
            }
        }

        // Initialize a Loader with id '1'. If the Loader with this id already
        // exists, then the LoaderManager will reuse the existing Loader.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    /**********************/
    /** LOADER CALLBACKS **/
    /**********************/

    @Override
    public Loader<List<TestSample>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateLoader(id) " + id);
        // return new TestSampleListLoader(getActivity());
        TestSampleListLoaderBis testSampleListLoaderBis = new TestSampleListLoaderBis(getActivity());
        return testSampleListLoaderBis;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<TestSample>> loader, List<TestSample> testSampleList) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished(): " + testSampleList.size());
        setListShown(false);
        mTestReaderAdapter.setData(testSampleList);

        if (isResumed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished(isResumed)");
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLoadFinished(isNotResumed)");
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<TestSample>> arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLoaderReset()");
        mTestReaderAdapter.setData(null);
    }
}
```

ADB Logcat Traces:

```
D/TestSampleListLoader(31166): onQeoReady!!!
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): initQeo(mTestSampleReader): org.qeo.internal.SampleReaderImpl@41d29e68

I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): TestSampleListener.onUpdate() => onContentChanged
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): onContentChanged()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): forceLoad()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): onForceLoad()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): forceLoad(deliverResult) 5
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): deliverResult(data) 5
I/TestSampleListFragment(31166): onLoadFinished(): 5
I/TestSampleListAdapter(31166): setData(): 5
I/TestSampleListAdapter(31166): setData() for testSample: Test Sample #1
I/TestSampleListAdapter(31166): setData() for testSample: Test Sample #2
I/TestSampleListAdapter(31166): setData() for testSample: Test Sample #3 UPDATED
I/TestSampleListAdapter(31166): setData() for testSample: Test Sample #4
I/TestSampleListAdapter(31166): setData() for testSample: Test Sample #6 UPDATED
I/TestSampleListFragment(31166): onLoadFinished(isResumed)

I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): TestSampleListener.onUpdate() => onContentChanged
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): onContentChanged()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): forceLoad()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): onForceLoad()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): forceLoad(deliverResult) 5
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): deliverResult(data) 5

I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): TestSampleListener.onUpdate() => onContentChanged
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): onContentChanged()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): forceLoad()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): onForceLoad()
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): forceLoad(deliverResult) 6
I/TestSampleListLoader(31166): deliverResult(data) 6
```

The problem is now that my **Loader** is correctly informed of data changes, but only the first time they are delivered correclty towards the **LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks** *onLoadFinished()* callback. After an orientation change, it's the same story, the first time result are correctly arriving in *onLoadFinished()*, but subsequent updates coming in from the native layer are not reaching the fragment.

I used eclipse debugging functionality to track down the problem and I found it in the **LoaderManager** sources (lines 447-453: this code is triggered from within the Loader.deliverResult => onLoadComplete [=> callOnLoadFinished => fragment update OK]):

```
// Notify of the new data so the app can switch out the old data before
// we try to destroy it.
if (mData != data || !mHaveData) {
    mData = data;
    mHaveData = true;
    if (mStarted) {
        callOnLoadFinished(loader, data);
    }
}
```

It seems that only the very first time **mData != data** (since **mData == null** in this case). In subsequent hits of this condition, **mData == data** always (and the data object/array is growing correctly with my native input), which is very weird because I cannot find out who is setting/updating this mData Object within the **LoaderInfo** class in the **LoaderManagerImpl**.

This issue is blocking me, because only if this condition  is true, the necessary call to *callOnLoadFinished* is done, which will correctly inform my fragment and arrayAdapter about underlying changes.

Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong in my custom Loader, or is a custom Loader not really a good solution when the underlying data set is changing all the time?

Thanks in advance!
Bart

Good reference on Android Custom Loaders:
http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html

Comment: Thank you for your question! I've spent half a day struggling with it! Had no idea it compares object instances under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

if you want data to. change i wolud remove mTestSampleList.clear() and replace it with mTestSampleList = new ArrayList();

Comment: pskink, that indeed solved the problem!

I guess clear is only clearing the references in the ArrayList towards the individual TestSample objects. Hence, from the ArrayList perspective (and hereby the LoaderManager), the array is not really changed (size is the same, only references are null-ified).

Great! Thanks again for the solution!